# How to pass variables to UI thread from worker thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, http

Below is the code for simple get request and **res** variable is not available inside Ui thread. How this can be achieved in android?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                String res = Utils.GetRequest("http://www.google.com");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out that I haven't declared the res variable as final.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try {
                final String res = Utils.GetRequest("http://www.google.com");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a handler on the Main thread in the OnCreate()

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
       // handle the passed value here 
       // for ex. update the UI by getting the data from the inputMessage 
    }
}
```

inside your Thread .. call the

```
Message myMessage = mHandler.obtainMessage();
myMessage.obj = "the value to update the ui";
mHandler.sendMessage(myMessage);
```